# How to create a git worktree of sub path

Tags: git, git-worktree, sparse-checkout

Is there something similar to `git worktree add directory commit-ish:SUB_PATH`?

---

### Use Case

I have the following structure

```
- alpha
  |- VERSION
    \- file.txt
  \- sub
- beta
```

And the goal is to check out the repo as following

```
- .git
- alpha
  |- v1
    |- .git
    \- file.txt
  |- v2
    |- .git
    \- file.txt
  |- v3
    |- .git
    \- file.txt
  \- sub
- beta
```

Where each of v1, v2 and v3 represent the name of a branch.
And it's desired to minimize the scripting, and rely mostly on git commands.

---

### Achieved Output

What I was able to reach so far is

by first `sparse-checkout` all directories except for `alpha\VERSION` and then `worktree add` the branch to alpha\v1. As seen below

```
- .git
- alpha
  |- v1
    |- .git
    |- alpha
      \- VERSION
        \- file.txt
      \- sub
    \- beta
  |- v2
    ...
  |- v3
    ...
  \- sub
- beta
```

Using the commands

```
git init
git config core.sparseheckout true
echo alpha/SUB > .git/info/sparse-checkout
echo beta >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
git remote add origin -f PATH_TO_REPO
git pull origin master
git worktree add alpha/v1 v1
```

Is it possible to `worktree add` only a subdirectory to reach the desired output?

Comment: Why do you want to put worktrees inside of other worktrees?

Comment: What would “worktree add only a subdirectory” do, concretely? I fail to understand what worktrees have to do with paths.

Comment: that means to get a worktree of a subdirectory of the repo at a specific commit/branch instead of getting a worktree of the repo's root at a specific commit/branch

Comment: based on my basic knowledge worktree does not do that. I'm not sure whether my knowledge is incomplete? or if there's some command that could do that ...?

Comment: `man git worktree` says that “--no-checkout can be used to suppress checkout in order to make customizations, such as configuring sparse-checkout.”. Maybe try `--no-checkout` and see if that helps?

Comment: Combining that with another sparse checkout for the worktrees, allows getting `alpha\v1\alpha\VERSION\file.txt` without having the other directories/files but still we can't reach `alpha\v1\file.txt*`